# Bayesian survival analysis

Tags: r, bayesian, survival-analysis

I am going through R's function `indeptCoxph` in the spBayesSurv package which fits a bayesian Cox model. I am confused by some of the input parameters to this functions. ( I also had some questions about the R code which I have posted separately here: [Stuck with package example code in R - simulating data to fit a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41342836/stuck-with-package-example-code-in-r-simulating-data-to-fit-a-model) ).

What is the role of the "prediction" input parameter? Should it not only contain the predictor covariates? In the R example, the authors have included a vector "s" which was used to initially simulate the survival times data in their example as well as the predictors. I'm not sure what this "s" is.

Given that my data is just a set of survival times between 0 and 100, along with censored (yes/no) information, how would I use this function and how should I handle the input "s"?

Comment: Surely looks like a duplicate of another Q you posted 2 hr ago.

Comment: The question is a bit different - more about the rationale of parameters and their role, the other question discusses specific parts of the  R code.

Comment: Still seems off-topic for SO for the resons I have already offered in other SO questions and Rhelp. Neither case is really about the R language. Both appear to ask about a fundamentally theoretical/methodological issue.  Best case is transfer to CrossValidated.com